# Multiple connections with same name are created in e2e test of NestJs with in memory database

Tags: testing, nestjs, in-memory-database, typeorm

I have NestJs application with TypeORM configured with mysql. I want to have e2e(integration) test and for that reason I want to have in memory database in the tests which I configured this way:

```
{
    type: 'sqlite',
    database: ':memory:',
    synchronize: true,
    dropSchema: true,
    entities: [`dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}`],
}
```

And the setup of the tests

```
beforeEach(async () => {
        const moduleFixture: TestingModule =
            await Test.createTestingModule({imports: [AppModule, UserModule]})
                .overrideProvider(TypeOrmConfigService).useClass(MockTypeOrmConfigService)
                .compile();

        app = await moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
        await app.init();
    });
```

. When running the test I got

```
AlreadyHasActiveConnectionError: Cannot create a new connection named "default", because connection with such name already exist and it now has an active connection session.
    at new AlreadyHasActiveConnectionError (/Users/user/workspace/app/src/error/AlreadyHasActiveConnectionError.ts:8:9)
    at ConnectionManager.Object.<anonymous>.ConnectionManager.create (/Users/user/workspace/app/src/connection/ConnectionManager.ts:57:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/workspace/app/src/index.ts:228:35)
    at step (/Users/user/workspace/app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:136:27)
    at Object.next (/Users/user/workspace/app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:117:57)
    at /Users/user/workspace/app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:110:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__awaiter (/Users/user/workspace/app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:106:16)
    at Object.createConnection (/Users/user/workspace/app/node_modules/typeorm/index.js:186:20)
    at rxjs_1.defer (/Users/user/workspace/app/node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm/dist/typeorm-core.module.js:151:29)
(node:19140) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AlreadyHasActiveConnectionError: Caught error after test environment was torn down
```

If I move the setup from beforeEach in beforeAll block it's ok, but I'm afraid that when I create several specs the error will come back. How should be handled properly?

EDIT:
The problem was that each test is making a setup of the application and so creates a new connection.The solution was to use "keepConnectionAlive: true," in order all tests to reuse same connection.

Answer (score 6):

`keepCOnnectionAlive: true` is the way to go

Answer (score 2):

Using `keepConnectionAlive: true` produced the following error for me.

> Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.
>
> This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't
> stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with
> `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.

Adding the below to each e2e test fixed my issue:

```
afterEach(async () => {
    await app.close();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Base on `0xCAP`'s answer, you can do something like this also.

```js
// jest.setup.ts
jest.mock("/path/to/database/config/object", () => {
    const { databaseConfig, ...rest } = jest.requireActual("/path/to/database/config/object")

    return {
        ...rest,
        databaseConfig: {
            ...databaseConfig,
            keepConnectionAlive: true // replace old config
        }
    }
})
```

```js
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  ...other options
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["jest.setup.ts"],
}
```